# Simple way to transpose each 6 rows into columns1, 2, 3 etc in Sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Thank you for your help! I really don't know how to do it..

Comment: No ID column or similar? Seems like you're lost...

Comment: How are the rows grouped? MySQL tables aren't ordered.

Comment: can you add text data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

Use PIVOT to convert rows to columns.

Take a look at [www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78) example;

```
SELECT  
  IFNULL(empId,'Totals') AS EmpId,       -- outer query labels rollup row 
  sums.2005, sums.2006, sums.2007,       -- and calculates horizontal sums 
  sums.2005 + sums.2006 + sums.2007 AS Sums 
FROM (                                   -- inner query groups by employee 
  SELECT                                 -- with an expression for each column 
    EmpID, 
    SUM(IF(Yr=2005,sales,0)) As '2005', 
    SUM(IF(Yr=2006,sales,0)) As '2006', 
    SUM(IF(Yr=2007,sales,0)) As '2007' 
  FROM Sales 
  GROUP BY EmpID WITH ROLLUP 
) AS sums; 

+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+ 
| EmpId  | 2005     | 2006     | 2007     | Sums      | 
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+ 
| 1      | 12000.00 | 18000.00 | 25000.00 |  55000.00 | 
| 2      | 15000.00 |  6000.00 |     0.00 |  21000.00 | 
| 3      |     0.00 | 20000.00 | 24000.00 |  44000.00 | 
| Totals | 27000.00 | 44000.00 | 49000.00 | 120000.00 | 
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
```